# Why are differential forms on a n-dimensional manifold a Grassmann algebra?

Tags: differential-geometry, grassmann-numbers

This is stated as an obvious example of a [Grassmann algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) on page 32 in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201124/) tutorial I am trying to read, but to me it is unfortunately not so obvious.

So can somebody expand this comment a bit and explain this to me?

Comment: If you just think of each $\theta_i$ as a one form, and wherever two of them are multiplied (e.g. in eq 2.1), just do the wedge product of forms, the relevant properties will appear e.g. $\theta^2=0$ because $\theta \wedge \theta = 0$ etc

Comment: The basic reason is dx^dy = -dy^dx.

Comment: I think this is just because Grassmann algebras are associative and anticommutative, which wedge products satisfy trivially.

$a\wedge (b \wedge c) = (a \wedge b) \wedge c$, and 

$a \wedge b = -b \wedge a$